# Wordpress MySQL - Query doesn't read value = '0'

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working a query for notifications about new messages. When a user send a message and the receiver has not still read it, the column `read` has value `0`. Of course when the receiver clicks on the message and reads it the database update the column `read` with `value = 1`.

My problem is that using this query:

```
$check_notification = $wpdb->get_results("
select *
  from {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_messages 
  join {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users 
    on {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_messages.id = {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.message_id 
 where {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.to_username = '{$session_uid}' 
   and {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.read = '0' 
 group 
    by {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.group_id");
```

`{$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.read = '0'` is not showing any message while if I change the value with '1', I get all the messages read.

It's not a database issue because I see through my phpmyadmin that there are messages with values 0 and messages with value 1.

Is it a formatting problem?

Comment: Have you tried it without the single quote ?

Comment: Did you try to get the query string and try it in a MySQL client?

Comment: @RaunakGupta what do you mean for a single quote?

Comment: @MikeVelazco I'm going to try it right now

Comment: There is no situation where it makes sense to use GROUP BY in connection with "SELECT *"

Comment: @XiLab: i mean have u try with 0 not '0', because the first one is treated as integer and the 2nd one is character. and what is the `datatype` of `read`?

Comment: @RaunakGupta, it is varchar(200), but I've tried that without results likewise. Damn.

Comment: @XiLab: try with this then replace 9 number line with this.
`and CAST({$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.read AS UNSIGNED) = 0` casting the character to integer value, then comparing.

Comment: thanks @RaunakGupta. I've closed the session and tried to reset the database. Next i've used again your suggestion using 0 instead of '0'. It worked! Write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are comparing Zero as a String it might creating a problem, try to `type cast vp_pms_group_users.read` to integer.

So replace 9 number line with this. 
`and CAST({$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users.read AS UNSIGNED) = 0`

If that field only contains digits then, I'll personality suggest to change the datatype of `vp_pms_group_users.read` from `varchar`to `tinyint(1)` so that you dont have to typecast all the time. (only if it is in development stage, otherwise ignore this suggestion).